# Is it possible to create a GraphQL subquery to create an array as an element of a markdownRemark?

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I'm making a webpage for a language school and am now trying to create pages about languages taught there. They're supposed to include the name of the language, a short descroption and a list of schedule items related to them. In Netlify CMS I made 2 collections for them. One of them has the general language information and the other one includes the schedule items.

What I would like to do when I enter a language's webpage is get the general infromation from the `language_pages` collection and an array of `schedule_items` with the same value in the `language` field, but I'm kind of scratching my head trying to figure out how to do it.

Each of the 2 collections includes a `templateKey` field, which differentiates between the collections. The values are `language-post` for general language information and `schedule-item` for schedule items.

My basic query to get a single language page is the following:

```
query {
 markdownRemark(frontmatter: { language: { eq: "Niemiecki" }}) {
  html
    frontmatter {
      language
      description
    }
  }
}
```

The field language also exists in the schedule item collection, so I'm thinking I should somehow use it to filter through the collection. I'm a complete graphQL noob, however and I haven't really found and example of what I'm trying to do here being done. My complete bodge-job resulted in something like this:

```
 query {
  markdownRemark(frontmatter: { language: { eq: "Niemiecki" }}) {
    html
    frontmatter {
      language
      description

    }
    children {
      id
      group
      room
      time
    }
  }
}
```

Which doesn't even execute properly and I'm honestly out of ideas how I could make it work.

Comment: so you have 2 folders for each collection, and they are both markdown & each has `language` as a field in `frontmatter`?

Comment: *a folder for each collection

Comment: Each collection has a folder, the include markown pages and have a language field in the frontmatter, correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do 2 queries side by side & filter by folder name with regex:

```
query LanguageInfo($lang: String) {
  languagePage: markdownRemark(
    frontmatter: { language: { eq: $lang }},
    fileAbsolutePath: {
        regex: "/your-language-folder-name/"
      }
  ) {
    frontmatter { ... }
  }

  scheduledItem: markdownRemark(
    frontmatter: { language: { eq: $lang }},
    fileAbsolutePath: {
        regex: "/your-schedule-folder-name/"
      }
  ) {
    frontmatter { ... }
  }
}
```

- `lang` could be a variable you pass into `createPage` action when you create page programmatically. You can then use it in your page template's query. Example from [the doc](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/actions/#createPage) in case you need it:

```
createPage({
  path: `/my-sweet-new-page/`,
  component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/my-sweet-new-page.js`),
  // The context is passed as props to the component as well
  // as into the component's GraphQL query.
  context: {
    lang: `english`,
  },
})
```

- `languagePage` & `scheduledItem` are alias name that make it easier to retrieve your data. You can access the data like `data.languagePage...` & `data.scheduledItem...`

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: I think this query does what I'm looking for, just need to adjust the rest of my code to fit it :) Thank you very much.

Comment: I can now confirm it worked as intended. Thank you very much again.

Comment: i there a public github repo to see how you resolved it?

Comment: Nope, sorry, I was doing a commercial project when I encountered this problem. The code is in a private repo. If you have any other questions however, I'll be happy to help